# Classifying numeric vector data

Tags: neural-networks

Neural Networks seem so complex these days.
Can anyone please suggest a simple structure (i.e. code) for training numeric vector data:  examples of 24 numeric inputs to produce 1 (integer) numeric output.
Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: P.S. I've been trying to use NetChain[] but unclear to me

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica SE. Can you provide some code that you tried, so that specific hints can be given. The problem is not totally clear to me.

Comment: Have a read of this documentation: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NeuralNetworksOverview.html particularly this part: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NeuralNetworksClassification.html#280210622

Comment: Use Decision Trees or Naive Bayesian Classifiers. E.g. `Classify[___,Method->"NaiveBayes"]`.

Comment: This question as written is too vague. It requires some indication of "typical" input and expected output. Along a minimal concrete example.

Answer (score 2):

The following code (1) takes example data -- a numerical matrix, (2) categorizes the last column, (3) picks 24 rows/vectors, (4) builds a classifier, and (5) tests the classifier over the rest of data's rows/vectors.

```
SeedRandom[323]

(* Get example data. *)
data = RandomSample[ExampleData[{"Statistics", "BostonHomes"}]];

Dimensions[data]

(* {506, 14} *)

(* Data summary. *)
ResourceFunction["RecordsSummary"][data]

(* Pick 24 vectors. *)
tind = 24;

(* Categorize the last column in order to make integer labels. *)
data[[All, -1]] = 
  Map[Piecewise[{{1, # < 17}, {2, 17 <= # < 22}, {3, 
       22 <= # < 25}, {4, # >= 50}}] &, data[[All, -1]]];

(* Train a Naive Bayesian Classifier. *)
cf = 
 Classify[data[[1 ;; tind, 1 ;; -2]] -> data[[1 ;; tind, -1]], 
  Method -> "NaiveBayes"]

(* Evaluate classification results. *)
Tally[
 MapThread[
  Equal, {cf[data[[tind + 1 ;; -1, 1 ;; -2]]], 
   data[[tind + 1 ;; -1, -1]]}]]

(* {{False, 215}, {True, 267}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Anton!
Unfortunately I had some very difficult circumstances, hence the very late reply.

Comment: @Putnik11 No problem. Good luck!